# How to keep lcd from affecting other windows?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, path

I usually have one tab containing the code I am working on, and another containing vimwiki. I mostly use neovim.

For the code I prefer the working directory sticking to the project root.  For vimwiki I have set in the `ftplugin/vimwiki.vim`: `lcd %:p:h`.
I switch the tabs with `gt`.

After a few edits - not immediately - in both tabs I notice the path of the "code" tab has been changed to the path of my current vimwiki page. Very annoying as the file name completion no longer gives me the project files.

Maybe I'm doing things wrong - but isn't it the main point of the `:lcd` command that it will leave other tabs and windows alone?

Any tips what could be going wrong? Or how I might debug this?

Comment: Is `autochdir` enabled? `set autochdir?`. I use this to ensure all buffers write to the same dir.

Comment: no. With autochdir I do not get the desired behavior that the work dir stays in the invocation directory.